# Web-scraping using rvest in parallel using parLapply (R)

Tags: r, web-scraping, parallel-processing, rvest

I have a large list (1.5 million) of string 'job titles' that I am using the O*NET online search function (https://www.onetonline.org/) to obtain an SOC code for. The basic scraping is very simple: I search using a string, and then take the first SOC code associated with the results, which is td[1].

For dummy purposes, here is an example of job titles:
`title_list <- c('doctor', 'research assistant', 'lawyer', 'sales associate insurance', 'chief financial officer and logistian')`

My scraping function is this:

```
scrapeONET <- function(title){
  library(stringr) # need for string manipulation
  library(rvest) # package for web scraping
  
  on.exit(close(link)) # ensure that the links are closed 

  t <- paste(unlist(str_split(title, "\\s+")), collapse="+") # manipulate the input title to the url string form
  link <- url(paste0("https://www.onetonline.org/find/quick?s=", t)) # open the url connection for the title

  tryCatch({
    page <- read_html(link) # read the webpage
    td <- page %>% html_nodes('body') %>% html_nodes("td") %>% html_text() # get a list of SOC codes
    return(td[1]) # return the first SOC code
  },
  error=function(cond) {
    return("") # if there is an error, return an empty string
  },
  warning=function(cond) {
    return("") # if there is a warning, return an empty string
    })
}

vscrapeONET <- Vectorize(scrapeONET)
```

Later, when I call the function in parallel, I set up the parallel environment as follows:

```
ncores <- detectCores() - 1 # define cores to be used
clust <- makeCluster(ncores) # start the cluster
scrape_match <- parLapply(clust, title_list, vscrapeONET) # use parLapply to return a named list of SOC codes
stopCluster(clust) # end the cluster
```

Upon testing my code, it will often run perfectly fine for a 1% or 5% sample of my data, however when running on the full list of titles, I always get the error: Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
N nodes produced errors; first error: cannot open the connection

I know that I must be setting up the parallel environment incorrectly or using rvest and webscraping with some poor practice such that the url connections are being invalidated. Another thought might be that I am overwhelming the O*NET search function given I use 31 cores for 1.5 million titles.

I thought that tryCatch would at least enable the code to continue to run if the url addresses are invalid and the scrape function cannot open or close the connections. However, even with tryCatch, the scrape_match object is never returned because of the checkForRemoteErrors error.

I have spent very many days on this and would appreciate any advice -- I'm sure I'm missing something silly.

Comment: https://github.com/eknud/ONETr

Comment: @Dubukay -- thank you! I should have mentioned I'm working on a machine with firewall issues that prevent the use of APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Futureverse](https://www.futureverse.org/) and `future_lapply()` instead of `parLapply()` for your parallelization, you should get a behavior more similar to `lapply()`, including getting an actual error object and not a summarized one:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

scrape_match <- future_lapply(title_list, vscrapeONET)
```

It's probably still not enough to troubleshoot what causes this. Then you could add poor man's debugging messages to your `vscrapeONET()` function, e.g.

```r
scrapeONET <- function(title){
  library(stringr) # need for string manipulation
  library(rvest) # package for web scraping
  
  on.exit(close(link)) # ensure that the links are closed 

  t <- paste(unlist(str_split(title, "\\s+")), collapse="+") # manipulate the input title to the url string form
  url <- paste0("https://www.onetonline.org/find/quick?s=", t)
  
  message("Opening url: ", url)
  link <- url(url) # open the url connection for the title
  message("URL opened")
  
  ...
}
```

This works, because contrary to **parallel**, the Futureverse will show you output from `message()`, `warning()`, `cat()`, `print()`, ...